# How unset a rule in sudoers?

Tags: linux, sudo

Now sudoers supports the subfolder `/etc/sudoers.d` where we can set personalized rules there.

I want use it and avoid changing the main `/etc/sudoers` file.

So, in a file into `/etc/sudoers.d/99_adjusts` I want to unset the main user specification rule :

```
ALL   ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I am trying to avoid commenting it out at `/etc/sudoers`.
I would want something which revokes this rule set before:

```
!ALL   ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

But the above unfortunately does not work;! looking at the man pages I can't figure out if there is some trick to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would want something which revokes this rule set before:
>
> `!ALL   ALL=(ALL) ALL`
>
> But the above unfortunately does not work

Naturally not. The `!ALL` at the beginning means "grant sudo permissions to no users," so the rule does nothing. It doesn't matter what follows on the line, it can't match anything.

It is possible to override `/etc/sudoers` via `/etc/sudoers.d`, as pointed out in the [`sudoers` man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html):

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).

Since the `sudoers.d` directory contents are pulled into the top-level `sudoers` file via a `#includedir` directive typically placed at the end of the file, adding a rule in `/etc/sudoers.d/*` will override any rule in the top-level file that is an equivalent match.

The correct syntax for overriding the rule in question is:

```
ALL ALL = (ALL) !ALL
```

What this says, left to right, is:

1. `ALL` users...
2. on `ALL` hosts...
3. may run the following commands as any one of the set of `ALL` users, defaulting to root...
4. which commands are `!ALL`

Since the last bit means "no commands," it completely overrides the "grant everyone all rights to run all commands" rule in your main `sudoers file`.

You then need to add any rules you want from the main `/etc/sudoers` file after this to restore their permission grants. This is a simple matter of selective copy-and-paste from the `/etc/sudoers` file. Remember: Last match wins.

**WARNING:** If you do not put anything after the above line into a file, you will have removed sudo permissions from *all* users. On a system where the `root` user is disabled, so that the `su` command doesn't work, you stand a high risk of inadvertently locking yourself out of the machine by messing with this. I suggest that you keep a separate `root` terminal open while testing this in another terminal.

---

This was verified on a macOS 10.12 system, but it should apply to any system that has the `#includedir` directive at the bottom of the main `sudoers` file.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, it is not possible to remove sudo rules in a sudo config file.

You should remove the main config file `/etc/sudoers` and write your rules only in `/etc/sudoers.d/*`.  Using both is source of confusion.

Comment: Sorry, but no. See my answer.